# Histograms of grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm fairly new to Python and getting my head around this has been really hard.

I have a code like this

```
df = p.read_csv("files/athena-query-1.txt", ";")
ax = df.hist(column="distance", range=[0.0, 0.5], bins=100, by="gate_id")
```

All I want is to see a distance distribution per gate on **separate charts**. If there are 400 `gate_id`, I want to see 400 distribution plots.

It tells me that the `ax` is a collection of `AxesSubplot`. When I try to plot this, I get only one graph that is unreadable. My guessing is that it tries to create a single chart (a Figure?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I reproduced a minimal example of what I think you might mean:

```
#create dataframe with 100 random values of normal distribution for 'distance', and distributing (1,2,3,4) as 'gate_id' evenly among the values: 
df=pd.DataFrame({'distance': scipy.stats.norm.rvs(size=100), 'gate_id': 25*[1,2,3,4]})

df.hist(column='distance', range=[0.0, 0.5], bins=100, by='gate_id')
```

This yields a figure with 4 subplots, corresponding to 'gate_id':

[image]

However if I try for 400 as you mentioned, the figure isn't even shown. Probably because its simply not big enough to hold 400 subplots. This is the reason I recommend the first solution example I gave below.

---

**ORIGINAL:**

If you want 400 seperate distribution plots, then why not create a 400 figures using matplotlib?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

for i in range(400):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(<dataframe['x']>,<dataframe['y']>)
```

*or* you can also try to plot a huge figure with many subplots, such as

```
fig, ( (ax1, ax2, ax3, ...<fill up here>..., ax10), (ax11, ..., ax20), ..., (ax91, ..., ax100)) = plt.subplots(nrows=10, ncols=10)

ax1.bar(<dataframe['x']>,<dataframe['y']>)
...
ax100.bar(<dataframe['x']>,<dataframe['y']>)
```

This is only for 100 subplots, not sure if 400 is just simply too big.

Comment: In your first code example, how does that fit with my `df.hist` result? I'm asking because it feels like I'm doing the right thing with `pandas` but I do not now what to do with the result of it. In your example, it looks like I should manually create a Dictionary of `<group_id, array[distance]>`?

Comment: You're right that this implies having a dataframe consisting of dictionary `{'group_id': array[distance]}`. Yes, `df.hist` is generated directly from `pandas`, while my first code example actually *manually* creates the subplots from the data. I don't doubt though that one can also do it well with just using `df.hist` in some way.